# Calling suitlet post from client script 2.0

Tags: netsuite

I have a suitelet to display records returned using a saved search. I have another suitelet which I'm using to show drill down results. In the first suitelet when the user clicks on the client it will be redirected to second suitlet. On the second suitelet there is button *Return To Summary* having click event handler in a separate client script. What I want is to return to the first suitelet post method upon click on Return to Summary button. The click event handler in the client script is getting called successfully but I am unable to call the post of the first suitelet in the event handler.

What I am doing till now to accomplish this is,
Client script code.

```
define(['N/https','N/url'],
function(https,url) {
    var exports = {};
        function backToSummary(filters){
            try
            {
                var array = filters.split(",");
                var data = {
                    custpage_client: array[0] != '' ? parseInt(array[0]) : array[0],
                    custpage_superclass: array[1] != '' ? parseInt(array[1]) : array[1],
                    custpage_startdate: array[2],
                    custpage_enddate: array[3]
                }
                

                postData=JSON.stringify(data);

                var scheme = 'https://';
                var host = url.resolveDomain({
                    hostType: url.HostType.APPLICATION
                    });
                var suitletURL = url.resolveScript({
                scriptId : 'customscript1235',
                deploymentId : 'customdeploy1'
                });

                console.log("URL", scheme + host + suitletURL);
                var response = https.post({
                    url  : scheme + host + suitletURL,
                    body : postData
                });

                // var scripturl = url.resolveScript({
                //     scriptId: 'customscript1235',
                //     deploymentId: 'customdeploy1'
                // });
                // var response = https.post({
                //     url: scripturl,
                //     body: postData,
                //     headers: header
                // });
                console.log(data);
            }
            catch(ex){
                console.log(ex);
            }
        }
    exports.backToSummary = backToSummary;
    return exports;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using https.post.promise (client scripts). Only server scripts are supported by https.post.